# Using webpack on a electron app

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

I'm new in Electron. I have seen some tutorials and videos where they use webpack or something called electron-webpack. I have use webpack for Angular and Vuejs apps bu those are web based technoligy. My question is What is/are the benefits of using webpack when working with electron?

Comment: The same. You know Electron is a browser, right?

Comment: @Dave Newton, yes I know that it uses Chromium and NodeJS

Comment: The output file webpack should be readable from your renderer process. I would discourage your to use Webpack for the main process though (Which is the NodeJS part). Since NodeJS does not support sourcemaps, and it is fully ES6 compatible. You just have to use CommonJS modules style (require) instead of ESM (import).